# Hiding Reports Based on Security in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: security, reporting-services

I currently have my report server set up so that a user's AD groups determines which reports they can run.  The user can be access the reports through either Report Manager or a custom site that I've created.

To reduce clutter, I would like to make it so that the user won't be able to see any reports or folders to which they do not have access.  I can't find a setting in Report Manager or a way to do this using the ReportService in my web app.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Report Manager does work that way. If they are seeing folders or reports, they have access and you may want to double check your authorization settings.

With regard to your custom application, you'll probably want to make sure you are passing in the logged in users credentials to the report server. If your custom application runs under a security context that has full access on the report server, then users will be able to access reports they shouldn't be able to access.